# How do I make a 2 row/column Wordpress layout with Flexbox?

Tags: html, flexbox, wordpress

I'm trying to port a portfolio site with a 2 row grid layout using flexbox, that wraps to a single column at smaller resolutions, to Wordpress. The layout is similar to [this portfolio site](http://ofanother.com/).

The code from the static site looks like this

```html
<div class="project-container">
  <div class="project-item">
    <h3 class="project-title">Project Title</h3>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/image-1500x1080.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="project-item">
    <h3 class="project-title">Project Title</h3>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/image-1500x1080.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

My current code using the Wordpress loop looks like this

```html
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php $args=array( 'post_type'=>'work' ); $query = new WP_QUERY( $args ); ?>

<div class="project-container">

  <?php if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>


  <div class="project-item">
    <h3 class="project-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
      <?php the_post_thumbnail( ''); ?>
    </a>
  </div>


  <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata; ?>

</div>
```

How do I get the loop to display 2 different projects?

Answer (score 0):

There're several ways to achieve this.

1.) Wrap 2 projects in a column
*You could do so by implementing a counter and check to close and open the column elements.*

2.) Via CSS
Check out grid layouts or look up the source code of the referenced website.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 700px){
    section.projlist a:nth-child(even) {
        margin-left: 0.65em;
        margin-right: 0;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 700px){
    section.projlist a:nth-child(even) {
        margin-left: 0.65em;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 700px){
    section.projlist a {
        width: calc(50% - 0.65em);
        max-width: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to add css to define the flex-box. The code should give you an idea. It looks similar to the example you mentioned

```css
.project-container {
  display: flex;
}
.project-item {
  margin: 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.project-item h3 {
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.project-item img {}
```

```html
<div class="project-container">
  <div class="project-item">
    <h3 class="project-title">Project Title</h3>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2/">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="project-item">
    <h3 class="project-title">Project Title</h3>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3/">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```